# Matlab GUI zoom buttons and scroll view for an axes

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm working on a matlab GUI, In my GUI there is a plot button and graph. I want to add two buttons first button is zoom in and second is zoom out. I want these buttons to zoom the plotted axes. I didn't find any code that zooms the graph. Plus I want to add a scroll view for the axes. Any help please for axes scroll view and zoom buttons codes.

Comment: Look at the end of [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/269448#865850) thread, a user posted a complete example in which a slider is used to zoom in/out.